# Flutter provider returns empty list after items are added to list

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I have a Flutter project, with Provider.
I set a MultiProvider in **main.dart**

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => VehiclesProvider(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Here is my **Vehicle Provider**.

```
class VehiclesProvider with ChangeNotifier, DiagnosticableTreeMixin {
  List<Vehicle> _vehicles = [];
  late VehicleDataModel _selectedVehicle;

  VehicleService _vehicleService = VehicleService();

  UnmodifiableListView get vehicles => UnmodifiableListView(_vehicles);

  dynamic get selectedVehicle => _selectedVehicle;

  void getData() async {
    final all = await _vehicleService.getAllVehicles();
    _vehicles.addAll(all.response);
    notifyListeners();

    final selected =
        await _vehicleService.getSelectedVehicleData(all.response.first.id);
    _selectedVehicle = selected;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

As you can see the idea is to store vehicles (coming from an API), then the user can select a vehicle (by default its the first). I followed the `getData()` with breakpoints, and everything seems to be working.

**But**

When I try to access the data... and I'm trying it multiple ways, I just can't. I only get this: `[]`

I tried to get them with a button's onclick function like this:

```
  getSelectedCar() {
    final p = Provider.of<VehiclesProvider>(context, listen: false);
    print('p.vehicles');
    print(p.vehicles);
    print(context.read<VehiclesProvider>().vehicles);
  }
```

and in the layout like this:

```
Text(jsonEncode(Provider.of<VehiclesProvider>(context).vehicles),),
```

Each way the only thing I get is the empty array. I'm showing a toast message when the data from the API is here, and only then I navigate to the screen where I want to access it, and try to push the button to get it, but nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to :

```
 final p = Provider.of<VehiclesProvider>(context, listen: true); // make listen : true.
```

So you get updated when the list is populated, in other words, when you `notifyListeners()`.

Comment: did it, got this error: 
Tried to listen to a value exposed with provider, from outside of the widget tree.

This is likely caused by an event handler (like a button's onPressed) that called
Provider.of without passing `listen: false`.

To fix, write:
Provider.of<VehiclesProvider>(context, listen: false);